# Promise of conversion from contingent to full time employee, however package and deadline are unclear

Tags: communication, salary, job-offer, fulltime, consultants

I work at a company X which keeps two types of employees, one as contingent workers(people from different organization but working for X) and another as full time employees who are X's own hires.

With this context set, I work at X as a contingent from a company Y. Due to many issues, such as lack of recognition, low hike from Y for the work I did at X etc, I sought to look for employment opportunities elsewhere and I got an offer from another organization Z.

Now **I have resigned from Y** and am serving the notice period for Y which is **60 days**. I also wanted to explore that if I could be converted to a full time employee at X.
I had a talk with my reporting manager from company X about my situation and on my request, he talked with the management and got my feedback(which was positive) and they agreed to get me converted to a full time employee for X, thus essentially removing the issues I was having by working for X through Y.

This communication with my manager was only verbal, and he told that as soon as openings come up(they don't have the opening's list now, as many people are on vacation), he would get me converted as a full time employee for X but the duration to convert me may take as long as 120 days from now.
In the meantime, he told me to talk to Y and **take back my resignation and continue working as a contingent**. Once he has information of the openings available at X, he would notify me, on which, I would once again submit my resignation at Y and X would initiate the procedure of buying me out from Y. (Y has certain clauses which X needs to fulfill should X want to convert any of Y's employees as their own)

Here are my questions :

1. Would it be okay to ask X that if they are going to match my compensation at Y and match my offer at Z (which is higher than Y)?
2. If I just accept to the verbal communication and cancel my resignation at Y and inform Z that I won't be able to join them since I would be retained by X, what options would I have, if later on X offers
   me a package less than that of Z or even less than my current package at Y? I would have lost my leveraging clauses.
3. What if Y decides that they would not let me go from their payrolls? (Since Y outsources resources to X, there are rumors that I heard, that prevents X from buying off Y's people until they both
   agree that Y is ready to let go and X is willing to take in that employee as a full time person)
4. Or should I back off and just join Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Asking the principal company (Company X) to match your salary at Company Y is probably going to be a non-starter. Company X hired you through Company Y because it was cheaper than hiring you as a FTE.  Often times, company Y doesn't have nearly the same benefits as company X.  So in many ways your over total compensation package is likely higher.  Asking them to match Z, however, my make more sense but you need to be able to show them that you will bring the value of the higher salary. But if the salary is higher than the your total compensation, you may have priced yourself out of the job. In situations like this, managers are often playing with the same amount of money. Either hire someone directly for $someAmount or contract with another company for less than that.  But with all that said...
2. I highly advise not to pitting the two companies against each other. It shows bad faith.  One way or another you're going to have to be dishonest with one of them.  It's better to either let them both know you are expecting an offer or you choose one and tell the other it's too late. Remember that your decision to switch companies is a business decision.  Likewise, Company X's lack of transparency is also a business decision.  If you want more money, Company Z is offering that NOW.  That's better than wishful thinking.
3. "Letting you go from their payroll" is not your problem unless you signed a contract.  If your contract says that you can leave for any reason, then you are exercising the clause in the contract. If you aren't sure about the terms of the contract, discuss it with an attorney.  The agreement between Company X and Company Y is not your concern.
4. Join Z if you think the company is better. I'm not sure how old you are or what your financial situation is. But most people leave managers. Money is often secondary. If you like company X, you may be happier there in the long run. But if you believe you'll have the same if not better manager at company Z, then take it.

Comment: Sorry for coming back this late, but your answer really helped and gave me a great perspective. Thanks for taking the time to write the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have no binding agreement with X that they'll actually hire you. In light of that, and the relationship between X and Y, and the fact that you've already submitted your resignation to Y, I'd be inclined to continue on your path to taking the job with Z.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yours was the first answer that I saw for my question,  and it really helped. Thanks :)